# For Looping Tkinter Button widget , change text through tuple

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i change the text field of a button inside a for loop  in Tkinter .
I wish to use an array type field for text which i can use to update the Button text inside a for loop  .

#!/usr/bin/python

```
from Tkinter import *


class Gui(Frame):

        def __init__(self,parent):
                Frame.__init__(self,parent)
                self.parent=parent
                self.mainframe_set()
        def mainframe_set(self):


                self.Nav_Frame=Frame(self.parent,bg="cyan")
                self.Nav_Frame.place(x=525,y=50,anchor=NW,height=390,width=190)
                self.Nav_Frame.config(highlightbackground='black',highlightthickness='5')
                var1=18
                var2=9
                self.nav_button=[]
                text_tuple={"B1","B2","B3","B4","B5"}
                for i in range(5):
                        self.nav_button[i].append(Button(self.Nav_Frame,textvariable=text_tuple{i})).place(x=var1,y=var2+40)


if __name__== "__main__":

        root = Tk()
        root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
        #root.config(cursor="none")
        app=Gui(root)
        app.mainloop()
```

I wish to create Buttons and then by looping ,input text variable to it from a tuple or list, but i dont know how to go about it .

Answer (score 0):

I changed one part in your code:

```
text_tuple=["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5"] #<- before you had set here, now list

for i in range(5):
    self.nav_button.append(Button(self.Nav_Frame, text=text_tuple[i])) #<-- you dont have any text variable created, so just set text argument.   
    self.nav_button[-1].pack() #<- pack better for the begining. Not sure how you want to place your buttons.
```